# установка MacOs

Tags: macos, установка

Возникла необходимость установить MacOs на acer aspire one 722 c62kk. В данный момент на нем установлена операционная система линукс(убунту). Возможно ли установить хоть какую-то версию MacOs, чтобы хоть как-то работала, и как легче будет это сделать, с убунту или же надо сначало установить винду?

Comment: Гуглить слово «Хакинтош». Выяснять подходит ли ваше железо (вряд ли) и нести свои кровные в магазин покупать макбук

Comment: Архитектуру тяжело будет эмулировать, но можно. [How To Install macOS in a Virtual Machine on Ubuntu Linux](https://www.makeuseof.com/macos-ubuntu-linux-virtual-machine/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробывать.